# Laravel: mark forum messages as read for new user

Tags: laravel, forum, user-registration

I use riari/laravel-forum in my project.
When a new user is registered forum for him looks like this:[forum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUdQa.png)

How mark all messages as read when registering a new user for this user?

Comment: The simplest way is if you run a for loop foreach message . But if you have a lot of message this could take a while. I had a similar problem a while ago and solved it by checking the unread only for posts (in my case) where created_at was after user created_at

Comment: Did you check it in riary controller or create new controller?

Comment: I created a function called 'countUnvisitedPosts' inside my category model (because each post was related to one category) and inside the function I iterated over all posts where created_at was after user created_at. Sure I had to iterate over a bunch of posts but not all posts

Comment: All is ok. Thank you.